# counting a cell if another cell contains a specific text

Tags: google-sheets

So I am working on a tool to help me with a game where I build a team. I currently have two stats that I am tracking. 1 being the amount of times I bring a certain pair of pokemon (which I already have a working formula for) and the other (the one I need help with) is tracking the pair of pokemons win %. I am looking to put the win percentage in a labeled column for a specific lead. I have a drop down menu for the selected lead and a check box for a win or a loss. I have attached the spreadsheet and I believe will make more sense once you see the sheet. I would like to be able to see the win percentage of the pokemon pair as I bring them. There are currently 80 games in the sheet and if someone can help with a formula on one I should be able to do them for the rest. Thanks!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mFUTKZcKiQw5vBfePDBf_iTC-u8NOdFBIoBoRlEO-bQ/edit?usp=sharing

I have not tried anything as I am stumped on where to being.

Answer (score 0):

### SUGGESTION

You could try to use this formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(T:T, M4, V:V, TRUE)/COUNTIF(T:T, M4)
```

Basically what this formula does is it checks what the chosen lead is on the dropdown (column T) and then checks if a checkbox is marked beside the win column (columns V)

And then it's just the quotient of the number of wins detected for that specific lead, over the number of games the pair has been played.

### OUTPUT

[image]

Comment: Let me know if this answers your question or if there are some things that needs to be clarified, so that I can adjust my answer accordingly.

Comment: This worked Perfectly. Thank you! Thought it was common place to leave a live link to an example document. A couple of weirdos got on there and messed around changed colors and left notes. Google has history of previous versions, not sure what they aimed to gain there LMAO. But like I said your solution was perfect. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Glad to know that this worked perfectly for you! In any case, feel free to click the accept button on the left (the check icon) or upvoting the answer, so that other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.